# Returning groups of correlated columns in pandas data frame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I've run a correlation matrix on a `pandas DataFrame`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame( {'one':[0.1, .32, .2, 0.4, 0.8], 'two':[.23, .18, .56, .61, .12], 'three':[.9, .3, .6, .5, .3], 'four':[.34, .75, .91, .19, .21], 'zive': [0.1, .32, .2, 0.4, 0.8], 'six':[.9, .3, .6, .5, .3], 'drive':[.9, .3, .6, .5, .3]})

corrMatrix=df.corr()
corrMatrix
           drive  four   one   six  three   two  zive
drive       1.00 -0.04 -0.75  1.00   1.00  0.24 -0.75
four       -0.04  1.00 -0.49 -0.04  -0.04  0.16 -0.49
one        -0.75 -0.49  1.00 -0.75  -0.75 -0.35  1.00
six         1.00 -0.04 -0.75  1.00   1.00  0.24 -0.75
three       1.00 -0.04 -0.75  1.00   1.00  0.24 -0.75
two         0.24  0.16 -0.35  0.24   0.24  1.00 -0.35
zive       -0.75 -0.49  1.00 -0.75  -0.75 -0.35  1.00
```

Now, I want to write some code to return the columns that are perfectly correlated (ie correlation ==1) in groups.

Optimally, I would want this:
`[['zive', 'one'], ['three', 'six', 'drive']]`

I've written the below code, which gives me `['drive', 'one', 'six', 'three', 'zive']`, but as you can see, they are just a bag of columns that have some sort of perfect correlation with some other column-- it does not put them in a distinctive grouping with their perfectly correlated cousin columns.

```
correlatedCols=[]
for col in corrMatrix:
    data=corrMatrix[col][corrMatrix[col]==1]
    if len(data)>1:
        correlatedCols.append(data.name)

correlatedCols  
['drive','one', 'six', 'three', 'zive']
```

**EDIT:**  Using the advice given by @Karl D., I get this:

```
cor = df.corr()
cor.loc[:,:] =  np.tril(cor.values, k=-1)
cor = cor.stack()
cor[cor ==1]
six    drive   1.00
three  drive   1.00
       six     1.00
zive   one     1.00
```

..which is not quite what I want -- since `[six, drive]` is not a grouping -- it's missing `'three'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a naive approach:

```
df=pd.DataFrame( {'one':[0.1, .32, .2, 0.4, 0.8], 'two':[.23, .18, .56, .61, .12], 'three':[.9, .3, .6, .5, .3], 'four':[.34, .75, .91, .19, .21], 'zive': [0.1, .32, .2, 0.4, 0.8], 'six':[.9, .3, .6, .5, .3], 'drive':[.9, .3, .6, .5, .3]})

corrMatrix=df.corr()

corrMatrix.loc[:,:] =  np.tril(corrMatrix, k=-1) # borrowed from Karl D's answer

already_in = set()
result = []
for col in corrMatrix:
    perfect_corr = corrMatrix[col][corrMatrix[col] == 1].index.tolist()
    if perfect_corr and col not in already_in:
        already_in.update(set(perfect_corr))
        perfect_corr.append(col)
        result.append(perfect_corr)
```

Result:

```
>>> result
[['six', 'three', 'drive'], ['zive', 'one']]
```

Comment: Works nicely. Thanks.

Comment: One follow-up question -- I'm now implementing this function over a datafame that's 3,856 columns wide by 100,000 rows long.  Since the function doesn't use multiprocessing, this is understandably very slow.  Looking at the `pandas` documentation, I don't see a way to make the `DataFrame.corr()` function to use multiprocessing.  Do you know of any functions that would create a correlation matrix on a dataframe that natively use multiprocessing? If not, would it warrant another SO question to work this out, or should we continue to iterate on this one?

Comment: @Bryan, I don't know of any such function or option, sorry. So perhaps it would be better to ask a different question.

Answer (score 10):

You could do something like the following:

```
>>> cor = df.corr()
>>> cor.loc[:,:] =  np.tril(cor, k=-1)
>>> cor = cor.stack()
>>> cor[cor > 0.9999]

three  six    1
zive   one    1
```

To match more closely your expected output you can do something like the following:

```
>>> cor[cor > 0.9999].to_dict().keys()

[('zive', 'one'), ('three', 'six')]
```

Explanation. First, I create a lower triangular version of the covariance matrix that excludes the diagonal (using numpy's `tril`):

```
>>> cor.loc[:,:] =  np.tril(cor.values, k=-1)

           four       one       six     three       two  zive
four   0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000  0.000000    -0
one   -0.489177  0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000     0
six   -0.039607 -0.747365  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000    -0
three -0.039607 -0.747365  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000    -0
two    0.159583 -0.351531  0.238102  0.238102  0.000000    -0
zive  -0.489177  1.000000 -0.747365 -0.747365 -0.351531     0
```

And then I stack the dataframe:

```
>>> cor = cor.stack()

four   four     0.000000
       one     -0.000000
       six     -0.000000
       three   -0.000000
       two      0.000000
       zive    -0.000000
one    four    -0.489177
       one      0.000000
       six     -0.000000
       three   -0.000000
       two     -0.000000
       zive     0.000000
six    four    -0.039607
       one     -0.747365
       six      0.000000
       three    0.000000
       two      0.000000
       zive    -0.000000
three  four    -0.039607
       one     -0.747365
       six      1.000000
       three    0.000000
       two      0.000000
       zive    -0.000000
two    four     0.159583
       one     -0.351531
       six      0.238102
       three    0.238102
       two      0.000000
       zive    -0.000000
zive   four    -0.489177
       one      1.000000
       six     -0.747365
       three   -0.747365
       two     -0.351531
       zive     0.000000
```

And then I can just grab the rows that equal one.

**Edit**:  I think this will get the form you want but it's not elegant:

```
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> cor.loc[:,:] =  np.tril(cor, k=-1)
>>> cor = cor.stack()
>>> ones = cor[cor > 0.999].reset_index().loc[:,['level_0','level_1']]
>>> ones = ones.query('level_0 not in level_1')
>>> ones.groupby('level_0').agg(lambda x: set(chain(x.level_0,x.level_1))).values

[[set(['six', 'drive', 'three'])]
 [set(['zive', 'one'])]]
```

Comment: Hmm... just tried it with one group of three correlated variables, but the output is a bit confusing. I'll alter my question to create this scenario.

Comment: I don't think the output is confusing It's just giving you all the perfectly correlated column pairs: which, based on your original question, is what I thought you wanted. But even though it gives equivalent information, it is not giving it to you in the form you want based  on you edit. Let me see if I can get it into the form you want.